# foreach() function behaves differently

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a simple user edit option. But I encountered the problem with `foreach()` function.
This is the code:

```
<div id="edit" class="modal hide fade" aria-labelledby="editModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 id="editModal">Hi, <?php echo $u['firstname']; ?>. Edit your profile right here</h4>
    </div>
        <?php foreach ($users as $u) {?>
    <div class="modal-body">
                         <?php  $id=$u['id'];?>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url("users/edit/$id")?>" method="post">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $u['firstname']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $u['lastname']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">User Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $u['username']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $u['email']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-success" name="edit">Save</button>
            </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    </div> 
<?php }?>
</div>
```

Problem is:
When I put `foreach()` function below any of my divs, I get the option to edit all the users of the database even of those whose `id` hasn't been passed. When I hit "Save" button all users get edited with same info.

But if `foreach()` function is put above all the divs, I used to get the option to edit the selected user but not now. It always echoes the data of first user of the database and when I edit it whole users of the database gets edited.

Why this happened? Am I missing something?

Comment: what variable holds your **$id** ? haven't seen the part you assign value to the $id

Comment: Actually this is the part of whole code and $id was declared above this code. Anyway I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you used a foorloop you created a `form` for each data on your database, when you put your `foreach` below your `div` im thinking that the `$id` on your `form` url is not the id of the selected data but the first data of the array. But when you put the `foreach` above your `form` element this also iterates the `$id` of your data that's why it updated only the data you choose to update.